# Помощь с lambda-функцией

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Требуется написать `lambda`-функцию.

Функция получает на вход число и строку. Строка представляет из себя последовательность команд, которые необходимо исполнить над числом.

Команда `1` прибавляет к числу 2
Команда `2` умножает число на 3

Примеры:

```py
print(f(0,  '12'))        # 6, так как (0 + 2)*3 = 6
print(f(1,  '21211'))     # 19
print(f(1,  '22222'))     # 243
print(f(-5, '12121212'))  # -165
```

У меня получилась такая `lambda`-функция:

```py
lambda x, y: [x+2 if int(y[j])==1 else x*3 if j==0 else (x+2 if int(y[j-1])==1 else x*3)+2 if int(y[j])==1 else (x+2 if int(y[j-1])==1 else x*3)*3 for j in range(len(y))]
```

Но она не работает так, как мне нужно.

Понимаю, что в `lambda`-функциях можно использовать рекурсию, но не знаю как применить её для решения моего вопроса.

Comment: Тут обычно не решают задачи за Вас. Вам надо хотя бы попробовать самостоятельно что-то написать

Comment: Подсказка: лямбды тоже могут быть рекурсивными

Comment: пробовала вначале написать обычную функцию, для  понимания логики 
но тоже где-то недопонимание
def y(x,z):
    for i in range(len(z)):
        rez = x
        if i==0:
            if int(z[i])==1:
                rez =  x+2
            elif int(z[i])==2:
                rez =  x*3
        else:
            if int(z[i])==1:
                rez = y(rez,z)+2
            elif int(z[i])==2:
                rez = y(rez,z)*3
    return  rez

Comment: `(lambda f: lambda num, op: f(f, num, op))(lambda f, num, op: (num + 2) if op == '1' else (num * 3) if op == '2' else f(f, f(f, num, op[0]), op[1:]))`

Comment: А зачем тут вообще рекурсия? Это же обычная агрегация: нулевой параметр - начальное значение, первый параметр - коллекция символов, которую и надо агрегировать. От этого и пляшем. На `python` не пишу, но более чем уверен, что он имеет какой-нибудь встроенный функционал a la `aggregate`

Comment: Товарищи, вопрос переоткройте: человек добавил свой код в вопрос

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Подскажите, пожалуйста, что такое агрегация? Где можно почитать об этом?

Comment: @nomnoms12: агрегация (условно) есть процесс объединения группы элементов в одну систему с использованием общего правила. [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: В `pandas` [агрегация присутствует](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_data_aggregation), но что-то не могу найти встроенного решения. Ладненько, используйте рекурсию хД

Comment: Вас интересует [свертка слева](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0), а не агрегация. В стандартной библиотеке python она реализована в функции [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

Comment: @extrn: свертка списка есть частный случай агрегации, но подмечено верно: это именно то, что нужно автору)

Answer (score 2):

Рекурсивное решение:

```py
(lambda f: lambda x, y: f(f, x, y))(lambda f, num, op: (num + 2) if op == '1' else (num * 3) if op == '2' else f(f, f(f, num, op[0]), op[1:]))
```

Обращаю внимание на то, что данная труЪ `lambda` не зависит от своего имени *(в тестах ниже я буду использовать переменную `func`, но исключительно для удобства)*.
Также `lambda` не использует никаких функций и дополнительных конструкций языка, аля, `list comprehension` и т. п.

---

Данную `lambda` можно разделить на 2 части:

1. `(lambda f: lambda x, y: f(f, x, y))`
2. `(lambda f, num, op: (num + 2) if op == '1' else (num * 3) if op == '2' else f(f, f(f, num, op[0]), op[1:]))`

Первая часть - это реализация рекурсии.
То есть, вызывая данную `lambda` будет возвращена новая `lambda`, которая сможет вызывать себя, благодаря тому, что хранит себя первым аргументом при вызове.

Вторая часть - это реализация Вашей задачи.
Тут я использовал 2 тернарных оператора для реализации конструкции `if-elif-else` и рекурсивный вызов, благодаря первому аргументу, поступающему в `lambda`.

Если проводить аналогию со стандартной функцией, то она будет выглядеть так:

```py
def func(num: int, op: str) -> int:
    if op == '1':
        return num + 2
    elif op == '2':
        return num * 3
    return func(func(num, op[0]), op[1:])
```

---

*Тесты:*

```py
func = (lambda f: lambda x, y: f(f, x, y))(lambda f, num, op: (num + 2) if op == '1' else (num * 3) if op == '2' else f(f, f(f, num, op[0]), op[1:]))

print(func(0, '12'))
print(func(1, '21211'))
print(func(1, '22222'))
print(func(-5, '12121212'))
```

*stdout:*

```py
6
19
243
-165
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import reduce

f = lambda _i, _s: reduce(lambda i, s: i+2 if s=='1' else i*3, [_i, *_s])

print(f(0, '12'))         # 6
print(f(1,  '21211'))     # 19
print(f(1,  '22222'))     # 243
print(f(-5, '12121212'))  # -165
```

Comment: У `reduce` есть 3-й аргумент, "подставляемый в начало списка, так что "конец" выражения можно записать `, _s, _i)` вместо `, [_i, *_s])`